# Connect multiple tables in different databases?

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with a query in PHP. I have 5 tables: contributions, employee, firm client and account.

client and contribution a junction joined with contribution by account. client is again junction joined with firm by employee.

Firm is joined to contribution  i.e

```
[(Table client---id_client).
 (Table account --id_account,id_client,id_contribution).
 (Table contribution---id contribution,id_account,id_firm).
 (Table firm---id_firm).
 (Table employee---id_employee,id_firm,id_client)]
```

How do I retrive contributions made of a specific client?

Comment: you should format your question to something readable

Comment: Okay sir i will do thats,its just it was my first time to ask a question on a blog am a new bie.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't need all five tables for your query. Try this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM contribution 
  INNER JOIN account ON account.id_account = contribution.id_account
WHERE account.id_client = xyz;
```

`xyz` is the client id you want to have the contributions for.

If you want to get the employee info also, you can JOIN that table as well:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM contribution 
  INNER JOIN account ON account.id_account = contribution.id_account
  INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id_client = account.id_client
WHERE account.id_client = xyz;
```

Comment: Am so grateful Sir!it worked so fine,what abt if i wanted to get the same results but this time through Table employee ,how would i go abt it?.Thanks you very much:)

Comment: I added this, but I am not sure if I understood you correctly. If you like my answer you can also upvote it :)

Comment: yes ur answer is very correct

Comment: I like ur answer en i have voted ,hope i have done it correctly,am new to the system:)thanks anyway